# Can't replace classifier on Densenet121 in pytorch

Tags: neural-network, classification, conv-neural-network, pytorch, transfer-learning

I am trying to do some transfer learning using this github DenseNet121 model (https://github.com/gaetandi/cheXpert.git). I'm running into issues resizing the classification layer from 14 to 2 outputs.

Relevant part of the github code is:

```
class DenseNet121(nn.Module):
    """Model modified.
    The architecture of our model is the same as standard DenseNet121
    except the classifier layer which has an additional sigmoid function.
    """
    def __init__(self, out_size):
        super(DenseNet121, self).__init__()
        self.densenet121 = torchvision.models.densenet121(pretrained=True)
        num_ftrs = self.densenet121.classifier.in_features
        self.densenet121.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(num_ftrs, out_size),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )
def forward(self, x):
    x = self.densenet121(x)
    return x
```

I load and init with:

```
# initialize and load the model
model = DenseNet121(nnClassCount).cuda()
model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model).cuda()
modeldict = torch.load("model_ones_3epoch_densenet.tar")
model.load_state_dict(modeldict['state_dict'])
```

It looks like DenseNet doesn't split layers up into children so `model = nn.Sequential(*list(modelRes.children())[:-1])` won't work.

`model.classifier = nn.Linear(1024, 2)` seems to work on default DenseNets, but with the modified classifier (additional sigmoid function) here it ends up just adding an additional classifier layer without replacing the original.

I've tried

```
model.classifier = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(1024, dset_classes_number), 
    nn.Sigmoid()
)
```

But am having the same added instead of replaced classifier issue:

```
...
      )
      (classifier): Sequential(
        (0): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=14, bias=True)
        (1): Sigmoid()
      )
    )
  )
  (classifier): Sequential(
    (0): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=2, bias=True)
    (1): Sigmoid()
  )
)
```

Comment: why do you say `self.densenet121.classifier = nn.Sequential(...)` not working? how so? what errors do you get?

Comment: No errors, just a duplicate classifier. I updated the question to show you what I get following print(model)

Comment: you only need to replace classifier once. You do it correctly insider __init__, you do not need to do it again

Comment: I want to load the state_dict from the pretrained model in before I change the classifier layer though. Don't I have to init with the 14 output, load weights, and then change the classifier?

Comment: this is exactly what you are doing in __init__

Comment: Not sure what you mean, if I init with outsize of 2, and then load_state_dict, i get `RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for DataParallel:
 size mismatch for module.densenet121.classifier.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([14, 1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([2, 1024]).
 size mismatch for module.densenet121.classifier.0.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([14]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([2]). ` I don't mean the default ImageNet pretrained weights, I am trying to load a specific state_dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace the `classifier` inside `densenet121` that is a member of your `model` you need to assign

```
model.densenet121.classifier = nn.Sequential(...)
```

Comment: This gives me `AttributeError: 'DataParallel' object has no attribute 'densenet121'`

Comment: Slight adjustment made it work: `model.module.densenet121.classifier = nn.Sequential(...)`

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your problem, the following code will solve

```
import torchvision.models as models
import torch
from torch import nn

import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
torch.manual_seed(0)




densenet121 = models.densenet121(pretrained=True)

for param in densenet121.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False

densenet121.classifier = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(1024, 14),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Dropout(0.4),


    nn.Linear(14, 2),
)


densenet121.cuda()
```